# Bash-like code completion in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vimrc

I'm currently using superTab for completions in Vim. However, I'd like the completions to be more like bash. For example, if I'm typing

```
st
```

and the possible completions are

```
struct, string
```

I'd like it to be completed to str if I press tab, and ideally display a menu of possible completions.

Plugins are OK.

Comment: Please don't post the identical question on multiple sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697498/bash-like-code-completion-in-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following plugin does what you're asking for:
[YouCompleteMe](http://val.markovic.io/blog/youcompleteme-a-fast-as-you-type-fuzzy-search-code-completion-engine-for-vim)

From the description:

> YouCompleteMe is a fast, as-you-type, fuzzy-search code completion engine for Vim. It has two completion engines: an identifier-based engine that works with every programming language and a semantic, Clang-based engine that provides semantic code completion for C/C++/Objective-C/Objective-C++ (from now on referred to as “the C-family languages”).

Answer (score 1):

Putting 
`set completeopt=menu,longest`
turns out to do the trick, mostly. Unfortunately entering some more text, then pressing tab again tries to do a full completion instead of giving the next longest common prefix.

Comment: I feel like that might be a supertab issue - adding `completeopt+=longest` makes it work more nicely for me using the native `CTRL-N` completion

Comment: Actually, I get what you mean... have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Building on Alexander's answer, I have something like these lines in my .vimrc

```
"unix like completion - longest substring
set completeopt+=longest
"add command to retrigger longest substring
"Naive version... see below
inoremap <C-m> <C-e><C-n>
```

So the 'longest' bit does most of the work, however subsequent presses of `<C-n>` will just start to cycle through the options.  If you press `<C-e>` that (e)nds autocompletion, triggering it again with `<C-n>` matches the next longest substring... adding a shortcut for that stops you having to press two keys....

You don't want to bind that to `<C-n>` as it will stop you cycling in the familiar manner

I chose M as it is right next to N and checking (`:h insert-index`) defaults to just being bound to `same as <CR>`.... because this is vim and nothing is ever easy it turns out that this means that vim can't actually [distinguish between the two keypresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935970/vim-how-to-map-ctrl-m-without-affecting-return-keypress-as-well)!

If you don't care about using `<C-m>` then just pick something else, otherwise read on...

Based on that other post I adapted the answer at the bottom and cleaned up the syntax a little (based on [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improve_completion_popup_menu))

I ended up with this:

```
"add command to retrigger longest substring
inoremap <expr> <C-M> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e><C-n>" : "\<C-m>"
```

pumvisible() returns a flag that says whether the pop-up menu is open.  This stops us changing the behaviour of the enter key in insert mode when the popup menu isn't open.

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation for the ? and : and why we have to pass strings in.